# Show that $f$ is one-to-one and compute $f^{-1}$ explicitly.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f = (f_l,f_2,f_3)$ be the vector-valued function defined (for every point $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ in $\Bbb R^3$ for which $x_l + x_2 + x_3 \neq -1$) as follows:
$$f_k(x_1, x_2, x_3) =\frac {x_k} {x_3 + 1 + x_1 + x_2}$$
$(k = 1, 2, 3)$.

Show that $J_f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^{-4}$.

Show that $f$ is one-to-one and
compute $f^{-1}$ explicitly.

I have show that the Jacobian is $ (1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^{-4}$. But unable to do the second part. Help Needed!

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the system
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
y_1 = \frac{x_1}{1 + s} \\
y_2 = \frac{x_2}{1 + s} \\
y_3 = \frac{x_3}{1 + s}
\end{cases} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
for $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, where $s = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$. $(1)$ is easy to solve as long as $s$ is solved, which can be obtained by adding three equations together.